# filebeat works from file but not from syslog with checkpoint module

Tags: syslog, elasticsearch

I'm trying send CheckPoint Firewall logs to Elasticsearch 8.0.
I have machine A 192.168.1.123 running Rsyslog receiving logs on port 514 that logs to a file and machine B 192.168.1.234 running Elasticsearch and Kibana. They are both Rocky Linux 8.5. For test purposes, firewalld is down and SELinux is set to Permissive on machine B

I was able to configure `/etc/filebeat/modules.d/checkpoint.yml` to read from file on machine A and send to Elasticsearch on machine B

```
- module: checkpoint
  firewall:
    enabled: true
    var.input: file
    var.paths: ["/rsyslog/Checkpoint.log"]
```

This is the relevant portion of `/etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml` on machine A:

```
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["machineB.mydomain.dom:9200"]
  protocol: "https"
  username: "elastic"
  password: "mypassword"
  ssl.verification_mode: none
```

If I check `/var/lib/filebeat/registry/filebeat/log.json` on machine A I see lots of lines including the field `"source":"/rsyslog/Checkpoint.log"` and if I browse Kibana on machine B I see the logs.

THE PROBLEM:

I would like to host the Elastic Stack all on machine B, therefore I configured Rsyslog to forward the logs from machine A to machine B on port 9001 and installed Filebeat on machine B.

`tcpdump` on machine B shows that the logs are being received

```
16:49:32.478830 IP 192.168.1.123.46757 > 192.168.1.234.9001: UDP, length 833
16:49:32.478853 IP 192.168.1.123.46757 > 192.168.1.234.9001: UDP, length 960
16:49:32.478966 IP 192.168.1.123.46757 > 192.168.1.234.9001: UDP, length 960
```

This is the configuration of `/etc/filebeat/modules.d/checkpoint.yml` on machine B:

```
- module: checkpoint
  firewall:
    enabled: true
    var.input: syslog
    var.syslog_host: 0.0.0.0
    var.syslog_port: 9001
```

And this is the relevant portion of `/etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml` on machine B:

```
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["localhost:9200"]
  protocol: "https"
  username: "elastic"
  password: "mypassword"
  ssl.verification_mode: none
```

`filebeat test output` returns OK

With this configuration, `/var/lib/filebeat/registry/filebeat/log.json` on machine B is empty, and if I browse Kibana I can see `filebeat-8.0.1-checkpoint-firewall-pipeline` under "Stack Management" > "Ingest Pipelines" but no logs are received if I go to "Home" > "Analytics" > "Discover"

I also tried to increase the log verbosity of filebeat by enabling

```
logging.level: debug
logging.selectors: [ beat, publisher, service ]
```

in `/etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml` but I don't see anything useful in the files inside `/var/log/filebeat/`

I don't know where else to look

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `var.syslog_host: 0.0.0.0` does not work.

It's either `var.syslog_host: 192.168.1.234`

or `var.syslog_host: machineB.mydomain.dom`